# Unexpected reserved word at "require"

Tags: javascript, node.js, requirejs

For fellow noobs who might see this issue when moving code between ES5 and ES6(Babel) projects.

Issue:  Using node 4.2.4, ES5, but not using Babel, received "Unexpected reserved word" at ... require().

> 'use 'strict'
>   var myLib = require('./lib/myLib');

Answer is below.

Answer (score -1):

The module at require('./lib/myLib') was using an

**import xyz from 'xyz'**

The exception thrown by node was not clear that this was an issue in the 'require' module.